# Bootstrap responsive menu not working for desktop

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap, navigation

I am having problems with bootstrap and Joomla with the collapsable nav menu. The site is at the link below:

http://spiffingtestdomain.com/bpp/

I've inserted the example collapsable navbar directly from the Bootstrap documentation underneath the menu I'm working on, and that doesn't work correctly, either. I'm sure I'm missing classes on my nav, but I can work that out if I can get the sample menu working. It is always collapsed as if displaying for mobile regardless of the screen width. I've checked the usual suspects (not loading jquery, not loading bootstrap files, screenwidth threshold) and none of this has helped. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: In your site I see a Toggler button that when pressed it toggles the appearance of a div below it - that contains a ul which contains: Link (current), Dropdown, and a search form... - I am not sure what you want us to check, What and how is it supposed to work whatever you are trying to do. Make sure you understand how everything works. Play and learn how to implement whatever you want on a pure html/css/js playground file and see if you are able to make it work there.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this. I'm trying to get the menu that is revealed by clicking the 'Toggle Navigation' button to appear with all menu items visible when the screen width is over 767px. I thought that this would only switch to a click-to-reveal menu when the screen width is 767px and under, but it is set to always be click-to-reveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Thanks to FFrewin for pointing me in the right direction. After testing a vanilla version of the menu, I used external bootstrap files from an example, rather than the ones bundled with Joomla.

P.s. note to future self: ALWAYS load JQuery first...

Comment: Hi @RichardChalkley, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the tick.